# How to use checkboxes to filter a mat-table in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, material-design

I am trying to use checkboxes to filter a table i have but everything i tried so far didn't work.

This is my a sample of my table :

```
 <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  [hidden]="!show" matSort >
    <!-- Location  -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="AITOR">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Location </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.AITOR}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
        <!-- Type  -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="SOG_MCOLH">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header > Container Type </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let container"> {{container.SOG_MCOLH}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
```

This is how my check box looks :

```
<input  class="CheckBoxClass" type="checkbox" value="RG" (onclick)="doFilter(RG)" >
<mdb-icon class="IconClass" fas icon="tint"></mdb-icon>
RG<br>
```

this is the function is use in my component :

```
public doFilter = (value: string) => {
  this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
}
```

I have tried using [checked] instead of (onclick) neither of them work.
I have tried using a Pipe but i didn't really understand it and how i should write it.
I have tried looking online for a solution but no one is doing a checkbox filter.

Comment: what exactly will this checkbox do?

Comment: as it states in the title filter the table.

Comment: Ok. What will happen (in table) if checkbox is in checked state and not unchecked state?

Comment: i get an error trim is undefiend when i use the [checked] in the checkbox.                     when i use the (onclick) nothing happends

Comment: try `(onclick)="doFilter('RG')"`

Comment: nothing happends

Comment: Please edit this example with your issue : https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-filter-by-column-uzrzuv 
That will make our life easier :)_

Comment: @AmitBaranes Hi this is a problem as most of the code is confidential to my work. and the Get method wont work out side of our internal network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this -

you need to make a custom `filterPredicate` in order to make use of `checkbox` for filtering.

Here is my code snippet with the new `filterPredicate` and html:

Html :

```
<div class="CheckBoxStyle">
<mat-checkbox  class="CheckBoxClass" value="RG" (change)="addFilter($event)">RG</mat-checkbox>
<mdb-icon class="IconClass" fas icon="tint"></mdb-icon>
</div>
```

Component - `filterPredicate` and the `method` that `observes` it and uses it :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.marinService.getAllContainers().subscribe((result)=>{
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result);
    this.total = this.dataSource.length;

    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: Container, filter: any) => {
      return filter.split(',').every((item: any) => data.SOG_MCOLH.indexOf(item) !== -1);
    };
    this.filterCheckboxes.subscribe((newFilterValue: any[]) => {
      this.dataSource.filter = newFilterValue.join(',');
        });
    )}        
  }

addFilter(change: MatCheckboxChange) {
  if (this.filterCheckboxes.value.some((a: any) => a === change.source.value)) {
    this.filterCheckboxes.next(this.filterCheckboxes.value.filter((a: any) => a !== change.source.value));
  } else {
    this.filterCheckboxes.next(this.filterCheckboxes.value.concat(change.source.value));
  }
}
```

This is the solution to using checkbox in filtering a `datatable` that worked for me.